# How to identify new line chars when file has both CR and CRLF characters

Tags: powershell, batch-file

[image: new line char and end of line both present]

I need to identify the new line chars if any using powershell or batch file and if present remove.

Comment: That will likely put everything on a single line without any (row) delimiter...

Comment: To answer your question as asked: ``.Replace("`r`n", '')`` or `-replace '\r\n'` would unconditionally remove all CRLF newlines

Comment: @mklement0 i want to keep flat file content as it is which is ending with CRLF but when i pressed "Enter" key , the notepad still showing CRLF. Can i identify new line char by naked eyes.

Comment: @Goks , You can not identify, which newline is used (LF or CRLF) by naked eyes, because those symbols are control characters. Some editors show those characters in a editor-specific way, some don't, some break when LF is used (under windows)

Comment: If you want to remove all linebreaks and are unsure whether the file uses CRLF or LF (CR alone is _very_ unusual): `(Get-Content -Raw path\to\input.ext) -replace '\r?\n' |Set-Content path\to\output.ext`

Comment: But in this case output.ext will have no line breaks. It will be single line `DTL|SRE|100DTL|SLW|100DTL|SLQ|100005359|100005362|806|SE146|MFGV|EA|100000`. 

Is that what you want ?

Comment: Pwesonally, I'd use `sed`, `gawk` or `awk`.

Comment: An editor will use the same newline format when you press Enter as is already in use in the file being edited, such as CRLF in your case. It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @filimonic : No , i want to keep the TXT flat file as it is with all rows and columns.

Comment: @Magoo : We have windows Server , not LINUX/UNIX , so can use batch or powershell.

Comment: @mklement0 We have 100+ flat files coming in TXT format with pipe delimiter containing thousands of rows and 100 columns . Each record starts from keyword : TEL such that TEL| 123|abc  . Now sometimes we get new line char resulting record coming in 2 lines so now record does not start with TEL anymore for that row. So loading in DB via ETL loads incomplete records.

Comment: Try googling for free windows ports of sed/gawk/awk. I have all three.

Comment: @Magoo : It's old server hosting Informatica running 1000 workflows , so confiugration can not be updated for a developer change. Files are coming from vendor (their UI system has free field txt field so people type enter while writing comments) which asking heft amount to fix , so we would like to fix on our end as developer.

Comment: @mklement0 : SORRY , each record starts with DTL not TEL etc.

Comment: Did someone perhaps remove all quotes from these files (and by doing so destroyed the field alignment)? Are there backup copies ?

Comment: @Goks, so what the expected result? If you want to keep files *as it is* then just do not touch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you state:

> each record starts with `DTL`

It sounds like the way to fix your file is to remove any newlines that *aren't followed by verbatim* `DTL|` (the code handles both CRLF and LF-only newlines):

```bash
# Create sample file.
@'
DTL|foo1
DTL|foo2
result of an unwanted
newline or two
DTL|foo3
'@ > test.txt

# Replace all newlines not directly followed by verbatim 'DTL|' 
# with a space (remove `, ' '` if you simply want to remove the newlines).
# Pipe to Set-Content -NoNewLine in order to save to a file as needed.
(Get-Content -Raw test.txt) -replace '\r?\n(?!DTL\||\z)', ' '
```

Output:

```
DTL|foo1
DTL|foo2 result of an unwanted newline or two
DTL|foo3
```

For an explanation of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) used with the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) above and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/6ezy7e/2).

Comment: Do we understand the question yet, lol?  Note that this code creates a text file with different line endings when run in the console `\`n`vs when run in a script `\`r\`n`.

Comment: @js2010, good point about the question. No, this code doesn't behave differently at the command prompt, because the file content is read and transformed _as a whole_.

Comment: @js2010, sorry, misread your comment: yes, the _sample_ file will have LF-only newlines if created at the prompt, but that doesn't matter here, given that the code handles both LF and CRLF newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't really understand what you want. You didn't posted any input file nor specified what is the output you want from such an input. Anyway, I hope this code can help:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a test file
set LF=^
%don't remove%
%these lines%

(
echo Line One: CR+LF
set /P "=Line Two: LF!LF!"
echo Line Three: CR+LF
) > test.txt < NUL

rem Read the file
set "acum=0"
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /O "^" test.txt') do (
   if not defined line (
      set "line=%%b"
   ) else (
      set /A "len=%%a-acum-2, acum=%%a"
      for %%n in (!len!) do if "!line:~%%n!" equ "" (
         echo !line!
      ) else (
         set /P "=!line!"
      )
      set "line=%%b"
   )
)) < NUL
for %%a in (test.txt) do set /A "len=%%~Za-acum-2"
(for %%n in (!len!) do if "!line:~%%n!" equ "" (
   echo !line!
) else (
   set /P "=!line!"
)) < NUL
```

Output:

```
Line One: CR+LF
Line Two: LFLine Three: CR+LF
```

This example first create a file with three lines, but the second one is ended in LF instead of CR+LF. Then, the program identify how each line ends and remove the alone LF's

The method is based on `findstr /O` switch that reports the *offset* of the first byte of each line starting from beginning of file